# mysqli/PHP - first two rows never show up(table with row data going across columns then moving down)

Tags: php, mysqli

My website currently ignores the first two images you place into the database and then proceeds to add images going across 5 columns and then moving down to the next row.

Update: Now it shows 3 of the 4 images in the database. Skips one image.

```
<?php
$i = 1; 
echo "<table>"; 
while ($row = $Recordset2->fetch_object()) { 
  if ($i == 1) { 
     echo "<tr>"; 
  } 
  echo '<td><img src="'.$row_Recordset2['ImgSource'].'" width="100" height="100"></td>'; 
  if ($i == 5) { 
     $i = 1; 
     echo "</tr>"; 
  } else { 
     $i++; 
  } 
} 
echo "</table>";   
?>
```

This is what my database looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFba8.jpg

This is what my website shows
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf7E1.jpg

Comment: You have an extra `$row = $Recordset2->fetch_object();` before your `while` loop. Remove that. And where does `$row_Recordset2` come from?

Comment: Alright, removed the extra line. (its now showing 3 of the 4 images)
Here is row_recordset2:
`$stmt->execute();
    $Recordset2 = $stmt->get_result();
    $row_Recordset2 = $Recordset2->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();
}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$i = 1;  
echo "<table>"; 
while ($row = $Recordset2->fetch_object()) { 
  if ($i == 1) { 
     echo "<tr>"; 
  } 
  echo '<td><img src="'.$row['ImgSource'].'" width="100" height="100"></td>'; 
  if ($i == 5) { 
     $i = 1; 
     echo "</tr>"; 
  } else { 
     $i++; 
  } 
} 
echo "</table>";   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
   <?php
    $i = 1;  
    echo "<table>"; 
    while ( $row = $Recordset2->fetch_object() ) { 
      if ($i == 1) { 
         echo "<tr>"; 
      } 
      echo '<td><img src="'.$row_Recordset2['ImgSource'].'" width="100" height="100"></td>'; 
      if ($i == 5) { 
         $i = 1; 
         echo "</tr>"; 
      } else { 
         $i++; 
      } 
    } 
    echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: That's just an endless loop with the same image.

Comment: Oops ! My mistake, Sorry Sir.